# Install CMake Tools after Visual Studio already installed

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

How do I install `C++ CMake tools` for Visual Studio if I have already finished installing Visual Studio? I know the Visual Studio installation wizard will prompt you if you want to install components of `Desktop development with C++` (which `C++ CMake tools` fall under), but how do I do that if I have already installed Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Visual Studio Community 2019, open it, under the `Tools` tab, click on `Get Tools and Features...`, under `Desktop development with C++`, select `MSVC` and `C++ CMake Tools`, and click on `Modify`.